# Multiple regexp match in Python (or logic?)

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of data with format like:

```
 /packagename-<digits> <someline>
```

I need to parse the `packagename` as well. The main problem is that it is also can be:

```
Package_Name
```

or

```
Package-Name
```

or

```
package-name
```

or even

```
package_name
```

I tried the following pattern:

```
(?<=\/)\w+
```

And well, it matches `packagename` as expected, but how should I parse the rest? It seems I failed to apply or logic or did it wrong.

Comment: what is *the rest*?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I mean I was able to parse only `packagename` and `package-name` but not the rest cases

Answer (score 0):

It's simple when you use groups:

```
import re

data = "/packagename-123 <someline>"
mo = re.search(r"(\w+)-(\d+)\s+(.*)$",
               data, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(mo.groups())
# -> ('packagename', '123', '<someline>')
```

The groups are:

- `\w+` to match the package name until the hyphen
- `\d+` to match the number until the space
- `.*` to match the remaining until the end.

Comment: well, your example covers the whole line rather than `packagename` and also, groups are useful, but what If I met not `package-name` but `package_name`? :) I can not predict what line will be look like and that's the problem here :(

Comment: @d.sci You need to adapt the RegEx according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a regex like this:

```
/\/package[-_]?name\D*(\d+)\s+(.+)$/i
```

[**`[Regex Demo]`**](https://regex101.com/r/DknffM/6)

```
\/package    => matches '/package'
[-_]?        => matches '-' or '_' or ''
name         => matches 'name'
\D*          => matches spaces,dashes or '' that comes before numbers
(\d+)        => matches <digits>
\s+          => at lease one space will follow
(.+)         => matches <some lines>
$            => to the end
/i           => insensitive flag for case insensitive
```

Comment: I need only different variations of `packagename`, not the whole line by groups:)

Comment: You mean just this `/package[-_]?name/i` ;).

Comment: i mean it could be `/packagename` or `/package_name` or `/Package-Name`  and so on where it can be different. For example it can has name PHP-Serializator, which matches with `Package-Name`

I actually have written `(?<=\/).*(?=-)`

which covers everything but `package_name` or `Package_Name`, do not know how to handle lower das here

Comment: What about [`(?<=\/)[Pp]ackage[\-\_]?[Nn]ame(?=[\-])`](https://regex101.com/r/DknffM/8)?

Comment: I've just finished more generic way:

`(?<=\/).*(?=-)|(\w+_\w+)`

Answer (score 0):

Think through the cases.

It would appear that "package name" is everything between a leading '/' and before a terminating `-<numbers><space>'`. The "space" is key, because you're not going to get a space in your package name (right?).

So, look at non-greedy match:

```
re.match(r'/(.*?)-[0-9]+ (.*)', data)
```

the `.*?` is a non-greedy form, so it will match "everything", but only so much as to allow the rest of the RE to match. The `-[0-9]+` bit, which allows you to "see" the end of the package.

The groupings `()` allow you to retrieve the results: The package name (without the numbers, (as I've written it) and the rest of the line.